# Angular scope.$watchCollection not checking collection more than once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, watch

I'm having issues with some code I'm writing that is supposed to utilize files that I am uploading.

---

### Explanation of problem

Basically, I have two parts to this mini-project I am working. The first part is a directive I've written that watches a file input and captures the files being uploaded. The captured file is then added to an array located on it's parent scope. The second part is a controller that watches the file array on its scope, which is the directives parent scope, using $watchCollection. The main issue is, the $watchCollection only fires once.

---

### Code

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="compareController as compareControl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card card-block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="card-title" for="fileOneInput">File One</label>
                        <input dropin 
                           files-binding="compareControl.file" 
                           type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileOneInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card card-block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="card-title" for="fileTwoInput">File Two</label>
                        <input dropin 
                            files-binding="compareControl.file" 
                            type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileTwoInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
           <p class="lead">{{compareControl.files}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

#### App.module.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
     .module('test',[]);
})();
```

#### App.compare.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('test')
    .controller('compareController', compareControl);

  compareControl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function compareControl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    var scope = $scope;
    vm.files = [];
    vm.file = [];

    scope.$watch('compareControl.file', comparer,true);

    function comparer(newCol, oldCol) {
      console.log(newCol);
      return (newCol === oldCol) ? console.log(-1) : vm.files.push(newCol);
    }
  }
})();
```

#### App.dropin.directive.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('test')
      .directive('dropin', dropin);


      function dropin(){
        var directive = {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: link,
          scope: {
            file: '=filesBinding'
          }
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope,elem,attr) {
          elem.bind('change', captureFiles);

          function captureFiles(){
            console.log(1);
            console.log(this.files);
            scope.file = this.files;
            console.log(scope.file);
          }
        }
      }
})();
```

I'm not sure why the $watchCollection isn't triggering on any new updates to compareControl.file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hrEIxMCFACNvDoYZZXuz) if anyone wants to mess with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I'm still not sure what the end issue was with my original code but for posterity, I'm posting the re-work I have come up with that is working.

### HTML

```
<body ng-app="test">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="compareController as compareControl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="card-title" for="fileOneInput">File One</label>
            <input onchange="angular.element(this).scope().captureFile(this)" 
               type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileOneInput">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="card-title" for="fileTwoInput">File Two</label>
            <input onchange="angular.element(this).scope().captureFile(this)" 
               type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileTwoInput">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
        <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #999; border-color: #999;">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" 
             ng-click="compareControl.compareFiles()">Compare Files</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block" >
          <p class="card-text">{{compareControl.results}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### App.compare.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('test')
    .controller('compareController', compareControl);

  compareControl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function compareControl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    var scope = $scope;
    var files = [];
    scope.captureFile = captureFile;
    vm.compareFiles = compareFiles;
    vm.results;

    function captureFile(file) {
      files.push(file);
    }

    function compareFiles() {

    }
  }
})();
```

### App.module.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('test',[]);
})();
```

---

### Summary

I'm not sure what the original issue was, but I came up with a re-work that doesn't experience the original issue and can capture and manipulate files. If anyone can figure the original issue, I would greatly appreciate it still. Either way, this is a working solution.

Comment: I upvote your question and answer because the well done documentation of question. About the possible solutions, you could replace the watch for $emit/$on events